# Equivalence of definitions of mutually singular measures

Tags: measure-theory

I'm wondering if these two definitions of mutually singular measure are equivalent? I've been trying to prove the equivalence but none of my attempts have been fruitful. Any suggestions would be much appreciated:

Let $\mu$ be a signed finite measure on $\mathcal{F}$ a sigma algebra on a set $\mathcal{X}$, and $\nu$ a finite positive measure on $\mathcal{F}$. Then $\mu \perp \nu$ if there exists a measurable $B$ such that $\mu(B^c) = 0 = \nu(B)$.

The second definition is with the same setup as above, except we now require for any measurable $E$, $\mu(B^c \cap E) = 0 = \nu(B \cap E)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent for positive measures.  The second one is fixed up so that it can be used for signed measures (or complex measures).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so then in the case of the Lebesgue decomposition of say, a finite signed measure $\mu$ with respect to a finite positive measure $\nu$, the decomposition is only unique with respect to the second definition that is fixed up for signed measures right? That is when proving uniqueness we must use the second definition, we can't use the first as it is false?

Comment: Just to be more clear, I have found that there exists a lebesgue decomposition for $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$, so that the mutually singular part of $\mu$ is in the sense of both definitions. Now I suspect to prove uniqueness this is unique only up to the second definition, not the first definition?

Comment: Yes.  If $\mu$ is a signed measure, then the set $B^c$ should not only satisfy $\mu(B^c)=0$ but $|\mu|(B^c)=0$, which means $\mu(E)=0$ for all $E \subseteq B^c$.  A "nullset" for $\mu$ is not merely a set $N$ where $\mu(N)$ is zero, but also all subsets of $N$.